# Is there a workaround to allow passing through tap/gesture events to widgets below a ModalRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a nested router in my Flutter app using `auto_router`, however I have a map widget (`flutter_map`) that appears below the nested router which I would like to still be able to receive gestures. These gestures are by default blocked by `ModalRoute`, and by extension `PageRoute`.

```dart
Stack(
  children: const [
    MapWidget(), // need gestures to also get passed through to this
    AutoRouter(), // renders child routes (PageRoute) which contain elements that should be clickable
  ],
),
```

[Based on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94997), it appears that there's no way to disable the gesture-blocking behavior of `ModalRoute`. Are there any good workarounds to allow the scenario above to function as intended, with the child routes being able to receive gestures without blocking them from propagating to the map below?

Comment: `ModalRoute` docs say: "A route that blocks interaction with previous routes" - so if you want to  interact with previous routes you have to use other `Route` class - most likely a custom `TransitionRoute`

Comment: I figured that might be the best way in theory, just given the incredible amount of code present in `ModalRoute`, I'm at a loss as to how to properly implement a custom `TransitionRoute` that works and supports Heroes and other functionality.

Comment: tried to extend `TransitionRoute`? it just requires 3 methods to override - two of them are simple `bool` getters

Comment: thanks! at your earlier suggestion I ended up trying that and with a few hiccups managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

At @pskink's advice, I ended up creating a custom route by extending `TransitionRoute` directly. While there is a pretty significant amount of logic in `ModalRoute`, most of this logic is not necessary for my particular use case.

This was the solution I came up with, a class that extends `TransitionRoute` and implements a `transitionBuilder` and `pageBuilder` which behave similarly to those in `ModalRoute`.

```dart
class TranslucentRoute<T> extends TransitionRoute<T> {
  final bool _opaque;
  final Duration _transitionDuration;
  final RouteTransitionsBuilder _transitionBuilder;
  final RoutePageBuilder _pageBuilder;

  TranslucentRoute({
    opaque = true,
    transitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    required RouteTransitionsBuilder transitionBuilder,
    required RoutePageBuilder pageBuilder,
    RouteSettings? settings,
  }):
    _opaque = opaque,
    _transitionDuration = transitionDuration,
    _transitionBuilder = transitionBuilder,
    _pageBuilder = pageBuilder,
    super(settings: settings);

  @override
  Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() {
    return <OverlayEntry>[
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => _transitionBuilder(
          context,
          animation!,
          secondaryAnimation!,
          _pageBuilder(
            context,
            animation!,
            secondaryAnimation!,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => _opaque;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => _transitionDuration;
}
```

Comment: btw, instead of "inventing" those two builder types (`final Widget Function(...`) use `RouteTransitionBuilder` and `WidgetBuilder` built-in types

Comment: your welcome, or of curiosity, does the current solution support "Heroes and other functionality"? I am wondering why they did not implement such `TranslucentRoute` in the flutter code...

Comment: heroes do seem to be working, but have some quirks, and i may need to look more into how `ModalRoute` uses offstage rendering to make them work as expected. there's definitely a lot of functionality implemented in `ModalRoute` (~745 LOC) but most of it is specific to the modal barrier, support for sliding route transitions like `CuppertinoPageRoute`, and other stuff that wasn't necessary for my use case.